# Loading a page within a jQuery UI-Dialogue causing an issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page which has a text field (has auto-fill feature, searching for persons/user in the database), using ajax to fetch back results as you type characters. If the results are 0, am adding a link beside the text field dynamically.So, On clicking the link it opens up a jQuery UI Dialog which loads a dynamic form that is used to add a new person/user.

Answer (score 1):

Check your page dom, jquery dialog inserts the new code into your original page, ensure the added html code is not causing your problem.

```
// Ensure the dialog is destroyed and removed.
$('dialogselector').dialog('destroy').remove()
```

Also you might want to add var dia for your variable so its not in global scope.

```
var dia = $("<div></div>").dialog({
```

Comment: It's not a global variable, declared it at the beginning of the function. $('dialogselector').dialog('destroy').remove(); no luck.. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The new code inserted by jQuery is deleted from the page DOM upon closing the UI Dialogue. {close:function(event,ui){ $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); $(this).detach();}}